# Trying to scrape a table from multiple webpages with a for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape information from multiple webpages for different MLB teams. These are the websites I am trying to scrape from https://www.covers.com/sport/baseball/mlb/teams/main/miami-marlins/2019 and https://www.covers.com/sport/baseball/mlb/teams/main/cleveland-indians/2019. For both teams I am trying to scrape info from the 12th table on the page and then join them together as a dataframe. so far my code looks like this

```r
library(rvest)
#> Loading required package: xml2
library(magrittr)
teams= c("miami-marlins", "cleveland-indians")

tables <- list()
index <- 1
for(i in teams){
  url <- paste0("https://www.covers.com/sport/baseball/mlb/teams/main/",(i),"/2019")
  table <- url %>% 
    read_html() %>% 
    html_nodes("table")%>%
    .[[12]]%>%
    html_table()
  
  tables[index] <- table
  
  index <- index + 1
  
  
}
#> Warning in tables[index] <- table: number of items to replace is not a multiple
#> of replacement length

#> Warning in tables[index] <- table: number of items to replace is not a multiple
#> of replacement length
df <- do.call("rbind", tables)
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>
When I run the code I get the above warning messages and the code only grabs the dates both teams played their games on. I borrowed the code mostly from the post [Trying to use rvest to loop a command to scrape tables from multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42356491/trying-to-use-rvest-to-loop-a-command-to-scrape-tables-from-multiple-pages) and then tried to tweak it a little bit to fit what I needed but obviously something about my alterations has messed it up. Below I have posted the code I wrote to scrape the tables from the individual websites which works well.

```r
url15 <- paste0("https://www.covers.com/sport/baseball/mlb/teams/main/miami-marlins/2019")
table <- url15 %>% 
  read_html() %>% 
  html_nodes("table")%>%
  .[[12]]%>%
  html_table()
#> Error in url15 %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[12]] %>% : could not find function "%>%"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-10-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

I would appreciate if someone could point out what I am doing wrong here and if possible explain it in layman's terms as I am very new to this.

Comment: You probably want `tables[[index]] <- table` since `tables` is a list and not a vector.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
library(rvest)
library(dplyr)
teams <- c("miami-marlins", "cleveland-indians")
dplyr::bind_rows(lapply(
  paste0("https://www.covers.com/sport/baseball/mlb/teams/main/", teams, "/2019"), 
  . %>% read_html() %>% html_nodes("table") %>% .[[12]] %>% html_table() %>% {`names<-`(.[-1L, ], .[1L, , drop = TRUE])}
))
```